# How many electrons should we remove?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electrons, charge

To get a charge $Q=1 \text{C}$, how many electrons should we remove from a metallic sphere?
I'm a aware that $Q=n.e$, but is this question true, because I believe we need an initial charge?

Comment: What is the problem with the *initial charge*?

Comment: @RogerVadim There's no initial charge, that's why I'm confused !

Comment: You mean that the initial charge is zero, and we need to remove electrons, so that the sphere becomes positively charged?

Comment: Well, that's not mentioned in the question !

Comment: Perhaps, this is what you are expected to know to answer it ;)

Comment: You are right, you need to know the initial charge value. The question does not explicitly state it, but it assumes that initially the sphere has a net charge of zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are being confused with charge and **net** charge. An uncharge sphere does have positive and negative charges, the only thing is that the magnitudes of positive and negative charges are equal and so there is no **net** charge.

Another way to think is that there are both electrons and protons in a metallic sphere right? Arent they both charged?

Answer (score 0):

Just assume the intial charge to be some constant $Q_0$. This gives the equation

$$Q = Q_0 + Q_e$$

where $Q_e=n(-e)$ is given by the number of electrons. You can easily solve this equation for $n$ with dependence on $Q_0$ and of course obtain the special case for $Q_0=0$. This equation then also tells you, how many electron you'd have to add, in case the sphere was more positively charged in the beginning.